# Publishing to Initialpose Programmatically on Turtlebot Navigation

Tags: navigation, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to set the initial pose of the turtlebot programmatically, and to do so I publish to initial pose using some code. I am following what is done here: http://answers.ros.org/question/114631/robot-estimated-pose/

I can publish to initial pose, but the robot will not react. When I set a new nav goal, the robot will continue from its previously calculated pose. Here is what rostopic echo /initialpose looks like:

```
    header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: map
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 100.0
      y: 102.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0267568523876
      w: 0.999641971333
  covariance: [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06853891945200942]
---
```

One interesting thing is that that header here shows seq to be 1, when I never set it to be 1 in my code.

My publishing code looks like this:

```
def talker():
pub = rospy.Publisher('/initialpose', geometry_msgs.msg.PoseWithCovarianceStamped, queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 10hz
    
pose = geometry_msgs.msg.PoseWithCovarianceStamped()
pose.header.frame_id = "map"
pose.pose.pose.position.x=100
pose.pose.pose.position.y=102
pose.pose.pose.position.z=0
pose.pose.covariance=[0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06853891945200942]
pose.pose.pose.orientation.z=0.0267568523876
pose.pose.pose.orientation.w=0.999641971333
    rospy.loginfo(pose)
    pub.publish(pose)
rospy.spin()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
try:
talker()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
pass

Does anyone know what might be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205308/publishing-to-initialpose-programmatically-on-turtlebot-navigation/) by [michaelyuan1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21789/michaelyuan1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is happening because publishers take a nonzero amount of time to start up. They will let you publish before they're ready, and silently fail. Simply waiting a bit before trying to publish will solve the problem.

To be really robust to startup issues like this, you should check that the message you sent has the desired consequence. In this case, you can publish in a loop, and wait for `amcl_pose` to be consistent with the `initialpose` that you published.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michaelyuan1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21789/michaelyuan1/) on 2015-03-18**:
Hi Dan, thanks for your answer!
I'm not sure if the publisher not starting up is the problem, because I do see the message coming out through rostopic echo. If the publisher were not up yet, I'd expect to not see any messages through rostopic echho

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-03-19**:
In that case, take a look at rqt_graph with amcl and your node running and make sure they're publishing and subscribing to the topics you expect.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Interestingly, the code will work if I change to one of two things:

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():  
        rospy.loginfo(pose)
        pub.publish(pose)
        rate.sleep()
```

or

```
pub.publish(pose)
rate.sleep()
pub.publish(pose)
rate.sleep()    
pub.publish(pose)
rate.sleep()
```

clearly there's some sort of strange time dependence here.

Anyone have an idea why this might be?

---

Originally posted by [michaelyuan1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21789/michaelyuan1/) with karma: 11 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michaelyuan1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21789/michaelyuan1/) on 2015-03-18**:
This code fragment stopped working...ROS is cruel